# Problem with lstlisting. Add color

Tags: color, languages

if I do this:

```
 \lstdefinelanguage{VHDL}{
    morekeywords={
        library,use,all,entity,IN,is,port,in,out,end,architecture,of,
        begin,and,END,THEN,ELSEIF,WHEN,IF,ELSE,EVENT,IS
      },

      morecomment=[l]--
    } 

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{keyword}{blue!100!black!80}
    \colorlet{comment}{green!40!black!90}
    \lstdefinestyle{vhdl}{
      language     = VHDL,
      basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
      keywordstyle = \color{keyword}\bfseries,
      commentstyle = \color{comment}
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=vhdl]
    -- (this is a VHDL comment)
    THEN
    1
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{document}
```

All good.

But I need other color.
If I do this,I have a problem:

```
    \lstdefinelanguage{VHDL}{
      morekeywords={
        library,use,all,entity,IN,is,port,in,out,end,architecture,of,
        begin,and,END,THEN,ELSEIF,WHEN,IF,ELSE,EVENT,IS
      },
morekeyword2s={
        1
      },
      morecomment=[l]--
    } 

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{keyword}{blue!100!black!80}
    \colorlet{keyword2}{red!100!black!80}
    \colorlet{comment}{green!40!black!90}
    \lstdefinestyle{vhdl}{
      language     = VHDL,
      basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
      keywordstyle = \color{keyword}\bfseries,
      commentstyle = \color{comment}
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=vhdl]
    -- (this is a VHDL comment)
    THEN
    1
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{document}
```

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: But , if I put a numer for example in red, the code no function

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your second `morekeywords` is wrong and you also have to define the second keyword style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{VHDL}{
    morekeywords={%
        library,use,all,entity,IN,is,port,in,out,end,architecture,
        of,begin,and,END,THEN,ELSEIF,WHEN,IF,ELSE,EVENT,IS
    },
    morekeywords=[2]{%
        RED
    },
    morecomment=[l]--
} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{keyword}{blue!100!black!80}
\colorlet{keyword2}{red!100!black!80}
\colorlet{comment}{green!40!black!90}
\lstdefinestyle{vhdl}{
    language     = VHDL,
    basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = \color{keyword}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle = [2]\color{keyword2},
    commentstyle = \color{comment}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=vhdl]
-- (this is a VHDL comment)
THEN
RED
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But , if I put a numer for example in red, the code no function. Thanlks!